# C++ on Linux not recognizing commands like exit() and printf()

Tags: c++, linux

I get these errors after issuing a g++ command on a .cpp file:
error: ‘exit’ was not declared in this scope
error: ‘printf’ was not declared in this scope

The problem is that when I compiled this program on another linux machine, everything went fine. I tried searching around, but all I found was that I need to include files like 'stdlib.h'.

Could it be I'm missing some library on my OS? If so, what might it be?

Comment: Please post the code, you are probably missing headers.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Recent versions of GCC have gotten stricter in what responsibilities the programmer needs to fulfill. Include the `cstdlib`, `cstdio`, etc. header and access these functions from the `std` namespace.

Comment: #include <sys/wait.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

This is the current header. Somehow it works with just this on other Linux OS, and I need to find out how. Adding extra headers to this is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Then compiling it under recent versions of GCC is *also* not an option at the moment. Your call.

Comment: Hmm, alright. Is there any way to circumvent this? Maybe install something somewhere or change some parameters? Do you have any idea between what versions of gcc this change occurred?

Comment: I don't know why you'd want to circumvent the standards. I mean, that just sounds silly... http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/porting_to.html http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/porting_to.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I know its kind of a weird thing to do, but it would make my life easier if I could, so I'd go out of my way to do it.

Comment: If you look at section 3 of the man pages, each page lists the header that a function is defined in. If you're using the function but not including the header (or the C++ equivalent), then, to put it in the vernacular, "ur doin it rong".

Answer (score 22):

Specifically for `‘exit’ was not declared in this scope` all you need is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Answer (score 3):

In terminal :- when you write 
man exit :- it will show

```
   exit - cause normal process termination
```

SYNOPSIS
       #include stdlib.h

```
   void exit(int status);
```

so you required to define header  #include stdlib.h

Answer (score 2):

If you are in need of a quick (and dirty) fix try:

```
using namespace std;
```

Also make sure you are including the appropriate io headers.